# Difference in the property value fetched in validate and model method in Struts2

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, model-driven, interceptorstack

I am running a basic Struts2 application in which I got one confusion.

My action class implements `Preparable` and `ModelDriven` interfaces and extends `ActionSupport` class.The model bean has a single property named `User`.

My home page(jsp) has one input field corresponding to the only property `User` of a model bean.

In `prepare()` method I am initializing the bean and setting its property to some default value say `"Test"` and the `getModel()` method is returning this bean object.

In `validate()`, I have a validation that if `User` property of bean has value equals to `"Test"` then `addFieldError()` else proceed.

```
public Student getModel() {
    System.out.println("inside getModel.."+ st.getName());      
    return st;
}

public void validate(){
    System.out.println("inside validate"+st.getName());
    if(st.getName().equals("Test")){
       addFieldError("name","blank field");
    }       
}

public void prepare() throws Exception {
    st = new Student();
    st.setName("Test");
}
```

Now, my question is

When I am accessing the action directly then the the error comes and in console I got below logs:

```
inside getModel..Test
inside getModel..Test
inside validate...Test
```

but If I input any value say `"Stack"` in the form field and submit the form then validate method prints the value that user has input while model method is printing what prepare has initialized.

```
inside getModel..Test
inside getModel..Test
inside validate...Stack
```

Why so? Why both methods are not in sync? Do the validate method and model method are picking the property value from different locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are get/set by the order of the interceptor invocations. As long as the action is on the valuestack, after `prepare()` the [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) is called `getModel()` to get the object whose property should be set.

The [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html) also retrieves model from the `valueStack`. Any subsequent searches for the model properties via expression results to call `getModel()` while the property isn't set yet. The `params` interceptor sets property finally, then [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html) is invoked, which is also retrieves `getModel()` to get the property values that should be already set.

The console will look like above. It's a normal behavior of the interceptors until the action is executed.

In the first case you didn't send values with the request, therefore the console prints what has been after `prepare()`.

In the second the value is sent and property has been changed, so the console reflected it. Values are coming with the http request, so it's the same "location" in the scope of request.

Comment: I missed the order in which the Interceptors run. Thanks.

Comment: @Infotechie It has the same order as in the config file from top to bottom. Look at the `interceptor-stack` tag.