# Struts2 actionError not displaying on jsp when action implemented ModelDriven

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, model-driven

I have my Struts2 Action class as below and I am expecting the actionerror message should be displayed in my JSP page using the tag: `<s:actionerror />`

However the message did not show up, and I've found that if I change in the `getModel()` method `return form;` to `return null;`, the error message could be displayed again! How can I show the error message at the same time returning the form object in `getModel()` method?

```
public class StartSearchApplicationAction 
                                      extends ActionSupport 
                                   implements ModelDriven, SessionAware {

    protected Map<String, Object> session;

    private Formbean form;

    public String execute() {             
        addActionError("Testing Error Message");
        session.put("form", form);
        return "success";
    }

    public Formbean getModel() {
        form = (Formbean) session.get("form");
        if (form == null) {
            form = new Formbean();
        }
        return form;
    }

    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session){
        this.session = session;
    }

}
```

---

Updated on 20-Oct-2015 - My JSP (it is the tiles template page)

Note that even I change the statement `<s:if test='%{#session.hasError == "Y"}'>` to `<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">`, the result is the same

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page errorPage="/jsp/error.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

<html>
<head>
<title><s:text name="global.heading.title"/></title>
</head>

<body>
<table class="main" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
          <td width="860" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <table border="0" valign="top" align="left">
<s:if test='%{#session.hasError == "Y"}'>
                  <tr>
            <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center" bgcolor="#006600">
            <tr> 
                <td width="16" class="ErrorMessageBoxTitle"><img src="/<s:text name="global.system.root"/>/images/smessage.gif" width="16" height="14" align="absmiddle" alt="System Errors"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2" class="FixTdSize"> 
                <table width="496" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr> 
                    <td align="center" class="FixTdSize"> 
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="12" cellpadding="0" width="480">
                    <tr> 
                        <td width="35" class="ErrorMessageTitle"><img src="/<s:text name="global.system.root"/>/images/messager.gif" width="31" height="31" alt="System Errors"></td>
                        <td class="ErrorMessageTitle" width="409">&nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> 
                        <td width="35" class="ErrorMessageBody">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="label" width="409"><font color=red><s:actionerror/></font></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
                  </tr>
          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>      
</s:if>
          <tr>
            <td height="30"><tiles:insertAttribute name="searchpanel"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><img src="/<s:text name="global.system.root"/>/images/line.gif" width="100%" height="2"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><tiles:insertAttribute name="message"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</table>

<tiles:insertAttribute name="menu"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just stop using modeldriven.

Comment: I would like to keep action class implementing ModelDriven as it brings much convenient to me

Comment: *it brings much convenient to me* - Such as? Not working validation?

Comment: Please, show your interceptor stack configuration

Comment: ... and post your JSP.

Comment: @Aleksandr M :
For example I can directly use the variable name in the jsp <s:property/> tag.

Is it necessary to post the jsp since it is too long. And the only tag to display error message is <s:actionerror /> which I can put it anywhere

Comment: @Andrea Ligios :
I am a newbie for Struts2, I did not add any interceptors to my struts.xml, is this answered your question?

Comment: Is your `<s:actionerror />` in some `if`? Does `execute` method is being called?

Comment: @HKCheung yes, I was initially thinking of an exception caused by null session because of ModelDriven interceptor put before the ServletConfig interceptor (that is the one injecting the session in SessionAware actions). But it can't be, because it wouldn't change anything between returning null or form from the method. Post your JSP, really :)

Comment: 1) Use `<s:if test="hasActionErrors()">` and 2) Try printing `<s:property value="%{'hasActionErrors() ? [' + hasActionErrors() + ']'}" />` before the s:if 3) Tell us IF THE EXECUTE METHOD IS RUN, by putting a system out inside it

Comment: @Andrea Ligios : 
1) Done 

3) Yes, system out message appears

2) If `return form;`, the answer is FALSE, 
If `return null;`, the naswer is TRUE

Comment: Maybe something with the tiles configuration ? Very strange

Comment: 1. Make sure that your `getModel()` doesn't throw unhandled exceptions. 2. Does `execute` method being called in both cases? BTW your markup is invalid.

Comment: @HKCheung You should read how modeldriven works http://stackoverflow.com/a/18044786/573032

Comment: @Roman C : You mean one of the default interceptors cleared my actionerror value? But I still wonder why the result is different between `return form;` and `return null;`

Comment: @HKCheung huh? it returns a model instance, the model affects the behavior of interceptors and valuestack state.

Comment: @Roman C : The action of pushing model instance to the value stack is before addActionError, still it cleared my error message? And stop using modeldriven is my only choice?

Comment: @HKCheung the validation action is also before it, if stopping the use of modeldriven is a choice why not you don't use it?

Answer (score 0):

after investigation I finally did it with referencing to this question:
[Passing parameters to action through ModelDriven in Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282400/passing-parameters-to-action-through-modeldriven-in-struts-2)

I think the reason is Modeldriven interceptor pushes the model on top of the value stack (i.e. 0-index) and thus the jsp could not access the actionError (the original 0-index was the action class).

Instead of using `<s:actionerror/>`, the page could able to display the actionError using `<s:property value="[1].actionErrors[0]"/>`, I am not sure whether this is a good approach but it serve the purpose.

Comment: @Roman C : I finally come up with an answer from your another post :) thanks for your help! As a newbie of Struts2, would like to ask if you think this is an acceptable approach? I am worrying if there will be other drawbacks.